# How to get PayPal user's currencies?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We need to list currencies associated with a given PayPal account, is there a way to accomplish this using the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is buyer-account data and is not available to API callers.